# How to crawl the intranet using screamingfrog?

Tags: seo, intranet

I am attempting to crawl an intranet site that is avail on url.prod.companyname.com.au (an internal site).

Just wondering if this is possible at all using any web crawler ?

Comment: Yes it is possible, is the answer. Perhaps if you elaborate more on why it's not working for you then we can be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the DNS records within the router that is at the gateway of your company (or within a subnet if the end point and client are within it) to point a specific domain to an internal IP it is absolutely doable.

Here's an [example](http://www.howtogeek.com/69696/how-to-access-your-machines-using-dns-names-with-dd-wrt/) with DD-WRT.